# I have a select list and I need to remake it on button group

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

**I need to remake a select form to button group without loss of functionality. I surf all Net but I can't find solution.** I can't do this without loss of functionality.

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
<select name="language">
    {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
    {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
    {% for language in languages %}
        <option value="{{ language.code }}" {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected {% endif %}>
            {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

From: 
[image]

To:
[image]

Comment: i don't know python but i was created fronted for you for [help](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WPvGQr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the select input, create separate `input` tags and set appropriate `name` and `value`:

```html
<form ... >

    ...

    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Choose Language">
        {% for language in languages %}
            <input type="submit" name="language" value="{{ language.code }}"
                   class="btn btn-secondary {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}active{% endif %}">

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the use [CheckboxSelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple) widget in your form and then change the way it looks using CSS and bootstrap, a `select` widget is not the right choice for achieving what you want.